# kivy capture keyboard behaves strangely on raspberrypi from xinitrc using screen manager

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, raspbian

I am attempting to make an embedded app on raspberryPi using kivy, I have an xinitrc which calls my app and the startscreen loads fine, but when I hit '1' or '2' my app goes to the second screen and immediately jumps back to the startscreen, until I hit the ctrl by accident at which point I get:

```
 Exception in thread Thread-4:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
         self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/hidinput.py", line 701, in _thread_run
         process_as_mouse_or_keyboard(*infos)
       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/hidinput.py", line 551, in process_as_mouse_or_keyboard
         Keyboard.keycodes[l.lower()],
     KeyError: 'ctrl'
```

And then it all works just fine.  I have a feeling it's something to do with the minimalist environment I am starting in.  Perhaps even something not loading yet, but a sleep 15 does not fix it, and I can just ctrl in less than 15 seconds so it seems that is not it.  Maybe I am just initiating the keyboard wrong.   Here's a small program that exhibits this behavior:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

import time
import random
import os

class StartScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
MyScreenManager:
    StartScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<StartScreen>:
    name: 'start'
    kbContainer: kbContainer
    BoxLayout:
        id: kbContainer
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#0000b1ff')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Welcome to the Example!'
            color: hex('#f8ee3fff')
            font_size: 30
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: hex('#0000b1ff')
                #color: hex('#cc2729ff')
                color: hex('#f8ee3fff')
                text: 'go to second'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'second'

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second'
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#0000b1ff')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'SecondScreen'
            font_size: 30
        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#0000b1ff')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 10
            spacing: 10
            Button:
                background_normal: ''
                border: (22,22,22,22)
                background_color: hex('#f8ee3fff')
                color: hex('#cc2729ff')
                text: 'go to start!'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'start'
''')


class ExampleApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            pass
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard have been closed!')
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print('The key', keycode, 'have been pressed')
        print(' - text is %r' % text)
        print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)
        if self.sm.current == "start":
            if keycode[1] == '1':
                self.sm.current = "second"
            elif keycode[1] == '2':
                self.sm.current = "second"
        elif self.sm.current == "second":
            if keycode[1] == '1':
                self.sm.current = "start"
            elif keycode[1] == '2':
                self.sm.current = "start"

        return True

    def build(self):
        self.sm = root_widget
        self.sm.current = "start"
        return self.sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Kivy App, there are two root widgets defined. One is from the kv file, `MyScreenManager:` and another one from Python code, `return self.sm`. Remove the second root widget as shown below.

```
def build(self):
    self.sm = root_widget
    return self.sm
```

[Screen Manager » Default First Screen Displayed](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#basic-usage)

> By default, the first screen added into the ScreenManager will be
>   displayed

Comment: commented out this line -->        `#self.sm = ScreenManager()`
and replaced with this line -->        `self.sm = root_widget`
But I don't see any difference?  Am I doing something wrong?  Notice it's not that the wrong screen manager is displayed, rather that the keyboard input does not seem to be working.

Comment: Adding an updated (still not working from xinitrc): https://gist.github.com/joshuacox/c0067d7dc7827aac2fd9be48e395e357

Comment: Sorry, we are not able to recreate the problem. *ColorScreen* is undefined in your app. Please share the minimal code for *ColorScreen*.

Comment: https://github.com/inclement/kivycrashcourse/blob/master/video14-using_a_screenmanager/main.py#L79   it was an adaptation of the crash course code there.

Comment: Have you tried directly from startx -> xinitrc ?  I updated the example to remove the colourscreen confusion https://gist.github.com/joshuacox/c0067d7dc7827aac2fd9be48e395e357

Answer (score 0):

The crash is actually caused by hidinput not handling the ctrl key correctly.
I have fixed this in hidinput and will try to do a PR for it once I figure out how to also not have the keycodes go through to the shell that I started kivy from.